# MySQL JSON_CONTAINS field value

Tags: mysql

I have this code:

```
(SELECT COUNT(streams.id) FROM streams 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(streams.server, '[\"servers.id"\"]')) AS streams_total
```

I have streams.id value in table (1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 etc) and would like to get using above mysql query this query so that it will work:

```
(SELECT COUNT(streams.id) FROM streams 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(streams.server, '[\"1"\"]')) AS streams_total
```

So i did not get idea how can i put into `JSON_CONTAINS []` field value so that it can return correct values

I can't pass value into `JSON_CONTAINS` from mysql field name (so that it using field_name it gets correct value)....what i im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
(
    SELECT COUNT(streams.id) 
    FROM streams 
    WHERE JSON_SEARCH(streams.server, 'all', servers.id) IS NOT NULL
) AS streams_total
```

And now it works...i im using node js using parallel mysql processing and it works like it should be...but i im not familiar with time response what is faster JSON_SEARCH or JSON_CONTAINS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should apply some changes in your query for getting proper output like below -

```
SELECT COUNT(streams.id) FROM streams 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`json`, '{"streams.server" : "1"}') AS streams_total
```

Comment: thanks...but i need to pass servers.id not "1" because i have in another table multiple servers.id's that is getting from 1 to 100 so i need to put servers.id not "1"..and don't know how to do that